# Add string to file at certain line number

Tags: sed

I want to add a string to file at certain line number in Linux. I searched and found a command like:

```
sed "5i helloworld" test.txt
```

to add `helloworld` at line 5, but I got an error:

> sed: command garbled.

I am testing in RedHat here. Is there any other command I can use here? Any other ways?

Comment: Are you using Linux or Solaris?

Comment: @miken32 linux here.

Comment: Then what you have will work, and why do you mention Solaris?

Comment: @miken32 I googled and see somewhere mentioned using sed in Solaris  , not sure if it is the same reason to linux here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Older seds are a bit pickier with how you type commands like `i`, `a` and `c`. Try an actual line continuation:

```
sed '5i\
helloworld' test.txt
```

The `i text` syntax is a GNU extension. POSIX sed only know about the `i\` version with linebreak.

Also, notice that there is a difference between the sed `i` **command**<sup>1</sup> (insert text) and the `-i` **option** (in-place editing).

---

<sup><sup>1</sup> Or "function".</sup>

Comment: _Optional reading_: To sum up the terminology conversation: Both the [_POSIX_ spec](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sed.html) and the [_BSD_ Sed man page](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=sed&sektion=&n=1) call the units of functionality available in scripts - such as `i` - a _function_, and an _instance of calling_ such a unit (the name of the function plus its arguments) a _command_. By contrast, [_GNU_ Sed's man page](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#Common-Commands) doesn't make this distinction and _only_ uses the term _command_.

Answer (score 0):

Here is `awk` solution:

```
 awk 'NR==5{1;print "Hey there this is new text added on line 5"}1' inputfile
```

Comment: I see error: awk: syntax error near line 1
awk: bailing out near line 1

Comment: @Richard this works fine for `awk` version `GNU Awk 3.1.7` . Are you sure its same or higher ?

Comment: Thanks for your info. And I see I also have gawk command available. my gawk is GNU Awk 4.1.0, API: 1.0. So change your command to gawk works for me. So command --- gawk 'NR==5{1;print "Hey there this is new text added on line 5"}1' test --- works fine on my server. I see both awk, gawk on my server. Not noticed gawk before.